# How to specifiy the number of decimal places using "ostream"

Tags: c++, ostream

I am getting a bit frustrated by my inability to get a double to print (to stdout) using the desired number of decimal places.

My current code looks like this:

```
void SomeFunction(vector<string> argv, ostream& oss){
   SomeClass ClassMembers ;
   string directory = argv.at(2) ;
   // specialized code that opens "FileName", defined by "directory"
   ClassMembers.GetValues(FileName) ;
   oss << ClassMembers.SomeNumber << endl ;
}
```

That is the general idea. The problem is that I cannot get ClassMember.SomeNumber to print out to, say, 5 decimal places by using:

```
oss << precision(5) ;
```

Note that "SomeNumber" is a class member that is declared as double.

It always gives me the number of decimal places that the parsed number found in the body of FileName has.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If it is always the same as input, then you must not be reading it as a `float` or `double` but instead as a `string`. `precision` will never affect strings.

Comment: I need to recast the string as a double somewhere else?

Comment: You should store `SomeNumber` as a float or double and read it from the file in that format (or read it into a temporary `string` and use `std::istringstream` to read it into `SomeNumber`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

oss.precision(5);
That should do it, according to [this page.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/)

So what you would want to do is this:

```
oss.precision(5);
oss << ClassMembers.SomeNumber << endl ;
```

Mind you the "precision" implies the **maximum** number of digits to display (not the minimum, so it will not include leading/trailing zeros or spaces).

If you want the precise number of decimal places to be used, use [std::fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) beforehand, like so:

```
oss.precision(5);
oss << std::fixed << ClassMembers.SomeNumber << endl;
```

Comment: Indeed. I have attempted this already, and it has no effect on the output.

Comment: To clarify: precision(float) is a member function of the ios_base class, NOT a global function.  You could not call it with "oss << precision(float)" because you are not specifying the object with which to call it, only passing what would be its return value, if it would compile.  That was why I assumed the OP had not used oss.precision(5).

Answer (score 4):

You might try to use [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) in combination. There can't be any more *unseen* digits, than have being parsed from your input.

Answer (score 1):

Set the flag for floatfield, and you should be able to get as many digits after the decimal place as you want.

```
#include<iomanip>
//...
oss.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);
oss.precision(5);
oss << ClassMembers.SomeNumber << endl;
```

If, for example, we were to use this method and print the value `12345.67` instead of `ClassMembers.SomeNumber`, the output would be:

> 12345.67000

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The question was "The problem is that I cannot get ClassMember.SomeNumber to print out to, say, 5 decimal places by using:" I answered it exactly.

Comment: Anyway you shouldn't give _code only_ answers, unless the problem is really obvious (and even then comment the code).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You are too fast! :-) I added my code first, and then the short sentence describing it almost immediately afterwards.

Comment: I know the problem ;) : When to click 'post answer' 1st time? Meanwhile, I don't care anymore, if a 'New Answer' bar appears while I'm typing my answers to complete a 1st shot. I type until I think it fulfills the minimal requirements for a valid SO answer. I always can delete after posting, if I see another answer given fits better.

Comment: I attempted the suggestion "oss.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield) ;", and the compiler returns with a "'ios' has not been declared" complaint...

Comment: @da5id: Note that you either need to `using namespace std;` or scope `ios` as `std::ios::fixed,std::ios::floatfield)`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this..

```
oss << setiosflags(ios::fixed);
oss << setprecision(5);
oss << ClassMembers.SomeNumber << endl ;
```

By using setprecision(5) alone, it includes the numbers before decimal place.

`E.g: 1234.777 become 1234.8`